# Dynamic include page by get response in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I need to make dynamic page with menu but i don't know how to do it on Laravel 5. I used to code like this with "pure PHP" :

```
$flag = 0;
if($page == "index")
{
    include("template/dashboard.php"); 
}
else if(in_array($page, $tempUPers)){
    include("template/ControlPages/".$page.".php");
}
```

And use this code to Get response:

```
 if(login_check($conn) == true){
  if(isset($_GET["page"]) == null){
      $page = "index";
  }
  else{ $page = $_GET["page"];}
 }
 else{
         echo '<script>window.location="../";</script>';
     //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../"/>';
     //header('Location: ../');
 }
```

As you can see, these code will help me to call(include) a php page which i uploaded to the hosting base on $page variable. So how can i do this on Laravel 5.1 ?, i am looking forward to your reply.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already a little experiences of the Framework? If not, start with the very basics.

If yes, you can take a look to Blade Templating and Middleware concepts to organize your code in a better way.

- [Blade Template](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/templates)
- [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware)

Also, you can use the **Request** component to get data from your current Request.

More details [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: yes i am, i worked with CI but not with Laravel. Can you give me an example code?.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I am actually a "newbie" here. How can I fix this?

Comment: Duong, if it's your first time with Laravel I suggest you reading all the basics. It's not something you can learn with simple examples: that's why I linked you that pages. However I am actually from my phone, I will link you some examples later!

Comment: @user1823151 thanks so much, i will try to learn from very basic lesson of laravel. I am looking forward to your examples :)

Answer (score 0):

If U R a newbie and want to learn **laravel** I would suggest

**http://learninglaravel.net**

Just create a account and read its book.

It will cover all the necessary topics and I assure U It covers everything 
from installation to CRUD(Create Read Update Delete) and many more